# Trying to use Sublime 3 to edit Jasmine test files

Tags: jasmine, sublimetext3

For months I've been using Sublime 3 to edit Python, Typescript, and CSS files.  It works fine.

Now I'm trying to use it to edit Jasmine test files.  In anticipation of this I installed this package: https://github.com/NicoSantangelo/sublime-jasmine

However, all of the Jasmine keywords like "describe", "beforeEach", "expect", etc. are all highlighted as errors.  I've tried following the plugin instructions but nothing seems to work to fix this.

Might anyone know how to get things working properly?

Robert